# Show that the identity function is the only ring homomorphism from $ℚ → ℚ$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that the answer involves the following, but I would like an explanation of why it works because I don't quite understand it:
If $f\colon ℚ → ℚ$ then $f(1/1)=1/1$, so $f(n/1)=n/1$ for all $n$ in $ℤ$. Also $f(1/n)=1/f(n)=1/n$, hence for integers $a$,$b$, $f(a/b)=f(a)f(1/b)=a·(1/b)=a/b$.

Comment: Which step doesn't make sense?

Comment: Do you understand why $f(1)=1$? Do you understand why that forces $f(n)=n$ for all integers $n$? and why that forces $f(1/n)=1/f(n)$?

Comment: Gerry Myerson, Yes, I do understand each of those things. The part that I don't understand is how you use those ideas to prove that the identity function is the ONLY homomorphism from Q to Q

Comment: You've shown that if $f$ is a homomorphism from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q$, then it is the identity homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

You have done all the work. If $f  \colon \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is a ring homomorphism you have shown that for any rational $q$ we have $f(q) = q$. But then $f$ **is** the identity function.